# How should I fit my curve in linear regression? : Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I've been trying to fit my curve. This is how it looks like:

[image]

I'm using mean squared error cost function. The MSE error is 19.8 and trying to minimize it more for best fit. How should I do it further? Here is my code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd


# In[95]:


train_features = pd.read_csv("training_set_X.csv", delimiter=',')
train_observations = pd.read_csv("training_set_Y.csv", delimiter=',')

print("Training features: ")
train_features


# In[96]:


print("Training observations: ")
train_observations


# In[97]:


print("Shape of training features = ", train_features.shape)
print("Shape of training observations = ", train_observations.shape)


# In[98]:


# Normalization of training data.
train_features_stddev_arr = np.std(train_features, axis=0)
train_features_mean_arr = np.mean(train_features, axis=0)
normalized_train_features = (train_features - train_features_mean_arr) / train_features_stddev_arr


# In[99]:


print("Training features: Standard deviation....")
train_features_stddev_arr


# In[100]:


print("Training featues: Mean....")
train_features_mean_arr


# In[101]:


print("Normalized training features....")
normalized_train_features


# In[102]:


# Layer parameters.
n_nodes_h11 = 5
n_nodes_h12 = 5
n_nodes_h13 = 3
no_features = 17
learning_rate = 0.1
epochs = 200


# In[103]:


cost_history = []


# In[104]:


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y')


# In[105]:


# Defining weights and biases.
first_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([no_features, n_nodes_h11], stddev=np.sqrt(2/no_features)))
second_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_h11, n_nodes_h12], stddev=np.sqrt(2/n_nodes_h11)))
third_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_h12, n_nodes_h13], stddev=np.sqrt(2/n_nodes_h12)))
output_weight = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_h13, 1], stddev=np.sqrt(2/n_nodes_h13)))


# In[106]:


first_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_h11], -1.0, 1.0))
second_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_h12], -1.0, 1.0))
third_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_h13], -1.0, 1.0))
output_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))


# In[107]:


# Defining activations of each layer.
first = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, first_weight) + first_bias)
second = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(first, second_weight) + second_bias)
third = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(second, third_weight) + third_bias)
output = tf.matmul(third, output_weight) + output_bias


# In[108]:


# Using Mean Squared Error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(output - Y, 2)/train_features.shape[0])


# In[109]:


# Using Gradient Descent algorithm
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# In[110]:


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# In[111]:


# Running the network.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for step in np.arange(epochs):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X:normalized_train_features, Y:train_observations})
        cost_history.append(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:normalized_train_features, Y:train_observations}))
        print (sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X:normalized_train_features, Y:train_observations}))

    pred_y = sess.run(output, feed_dict={X:normalized_train_features})
    plt.plot(range(len(pred_y)), pred_y)
    plt.plot(range(len(train_observations)), train_observations)


# In[112]:


plt.savefig('fig2.png')
plt.show()
```

The learning rate is 0.1 and I'm using stochastic gradient descent technique. I've tried to reduce error using Adam Optimizer with learning rates 0.01 and 0.5 but I was getting an error around 89.21. It would be great if anyone can provide me a better solution to reduce MSE error for best curve fit.

Comment: Is your specific use case to simply approximate the given line as best as possible, or are you doing further predictions on it?
Also, if you are trying to reduce the maximum deviation from the curve and predicted values, you might want to add regularization for the maximum difference, or something similar...

Comment: I'm actually new to this. How should I do it? I simply want to approximate the given line as best as possible i.e the best curve fit with less MSE error.

Comment: For that, I would consider approaches not using Neural Networks, since they inherently try to describe a system in a more general way. For curve fitting, many of the provided tools in [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), or if you really want to stick to a more "learning-based" approach, consider some of the classical techniques like polynomial fitting ([Scikit-learn has functions for this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html))

Comment: Alright. Thanks, I'll try to follow your approach.